# Fix IE error when adding two Minicslider (nivoliders)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, compatibility, prestashop

I have the following error. My page looks bad on IE, but it looks ok in all other browsers. This problem happened when I tried to copy the Minicslider module by NivoSlider . There are not repeated JQuery calls, everything seems in order, but I dont know what is happening. I am working under Prestashop.

Page: www.adroid.cl/agualpalo

If anybody is willing to help me on this, I would really appreciate it. Thanks

PS: codes are long, so I didn't paste them now. But I will accordingly to what I am asked.